# Adding a normal vector to a curved mesh area

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

How can I put a normal vector on the outer blue mesh?

[TeXample](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/spherical-and-cartesian-grids/)

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,fadings,decorations.pathreplacing}

\newcommand\pgfmathsinandcos[3]{%                                                  
  \pgfmathsetmacro#1{sin(#3)}%                                                     
  \pgfmathsetmacro#2{cos(#3)}%                                                     
}
\newcommand\LongitudePlane[3][current plane]{%                                     
  \pgfmathsinandcos\sinEl\cosEl{#2} % elevation                                    
  \pgfmathsinandcos\sint\cost{#3} % azimuth                                        
  \tikzset{#1/.estyle = {cm = {\cost, \sint*\sinEl, 0, \cosEl, (0,0)}}}            
}
\newcommand\LatitudePlane[3][current plane]{%                                      
  \pgfmathsinandcos\sinEl\cosEl{#2} % elevation                                    
  \pgfmathsinandcos\sint\cost{#3} % latitude                                       
  \pgfmathsetmacro\yshift{\cosEl*\sint}                                            
  \tikzset{#1/.estyle = {cm = {\cost, 0, 0, \cost*\sinEl, (0,\yshift)}}} %         
}
\newcommand\DrawLongitudeCircle[2][1]{                                             
  \LongitudePlane{\angEl}{#2}                                                      
  \tikzset{current plane/.prefix style = {scale = #1}}                             
  % angle of "visibility"                                                          
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angVis{atan(sin(#2)*cos(\angEl)/sin(\angEl))} %                 
  \draw[current plane] (\angVis:1) arc (\angVis:\angVis + 180:1);                  
  \draw[current plane, dashed] (\angVis - 180:1) arc (\angVis - 180:\angVis:1);    
}
\newcommand\DrawLatitudeCircle[2][1]{                                              
  \LatitudePlane{\angEl}{#2}                                                       
  \tikzset{current plane/.prefix style = {scale = #1}}                             
  \pgfmathsetmacro\sinVis{sin(#2)/cos(#2)*sin(\angEl)/cos(\angEl)}                 
  % angle of "visibility"                                                          
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angVis{asin(min(1,max(\sinVis,-1)))}                            
  \draw[current plane] (\angVis:1) arc (\angVis:-\angVis - 180:1);                 
  \draw[current plane, dashed] (180 - \angVis:1) arc (180 - \angVis:\angVis:1);    
}
\newcommand\DrawLongitudeCirclered[2][1]{                                          
     \LongitudePlane{\angEl}{#2}                                                     
   \tikzset{current plane/.prefix style={scale=#1}}                                 
  % angle of "visibility"                                                          
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angVis{atan(sin(#2)*cos(\angEl)/sin(\angEl))} %                 
  \draw[current plane, blue, thick] (150:1) arc (150:180:1);                       
  % \draw[current plane,dashed] (-50:1) arc (-50:-35:1);                           
}%for drawing the grid                                                             
\newcommand\DLongredd[2][1]{                                                       
  \LongitudePlane{\angEl}{#2}                                                     
  \tikzset{current plane/.prefix style={scale=#1}}                                 
  % angle of "visibility"                                                          
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angVis{atan(sin(#2)*cos(\angEl)/sin(\angEl))} %                 
  \draw[current plane, black, dashed, ultra thick] (150:1) arc (150:180:1);        
}
\newcommand\DLatred[2][1]{                                                         
  \LatitudePlane{\angEl}{#2}                                                      
  \tikzset{current plane/.prefix style={scale=#1}}                                 
  \pgfmathsetmacro\sinVis{sin(#2)/cos(#2)*sin(\angEl)/cos(\angEl)}                 
  % angle of "visibility"                                                          
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angVis{asin(min(1,max(\sinVis,-1)))}                            
  \draw[current plane, dashed, black, ultra thick] (-50:1) arc (-50:-35:1);        
}
\newcommand  \fillred[2][1]{                                                         
  \LongitudePlane{\angEl}{#2}                                                     
  \tikzset{current plane/.prefix style={scale=#1}}                                 
  % angle of "visibility"                                                          
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angVis{atan(sin(#2)*cos(\angEl)/sin(\angEl))} %                 
  \draw[current plane, blue, thin] (\angVis:1) arc (\angVis:\angVis+180:1);        
}
\newcommand\DrawLatitudeCirclered[2][1]{                                           
  \LatitudePlane{\angEl}{#2}                                                      
  \tikzset{current plane/.prefix style={scale=#1}}                                 
  \pgfmathsetmacro\sinVis{sin(#2)/cos(#2)*sin(\angEl)/cos(\angEl)}                 
  % angle of "visibility"                                                          
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angVis{asin(min(1,max(\sinVis,-1)))}                            
% \draw[current plane,red,thick] (-\angVis-50:1) arc (-\angVis-50:-\angVis-20:1);  
  \draw[current plane, blue, thick] (-50:1) arc (-50:-35:1);                       
}


\tikzset{%                                                                        
  >=latex, % option for nice arrows                                               
  inner sep = 0pt,%                                                               
  outer sep = 2pt,%                                                               
  mark coordinate/.style = {inner sep = 0pt, outer sep = 0pt, minimum size = 3pt,
    fill = black, circle}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\R{2} % sphere radius                                                      

\def\angEl{25} % elevation angle                                               
\def\angAz{-100} % azimuth angle                                               
\def\angPhiOne{-50} % longitude of point P                                     
\def\angPhiTwo{-35} % longitude of point Q                                     
\def\angBeta{30} % latitude of point P and Q                                   

%% working planes                                                              

\pgfmathsetmacro\H{\R*cos(\angEl)} % distance to north pole                    
\LongitudePlane[xzplane]{\angEl}{\angAz}
\LongitudePlane[pzplane]{\angEl}{\angPhiOne}
\LongitudePlane[qzplane]{\angEl}{\angPhiTwo}
\LatitudePlane[equator]{\angEl}{0}
\fill[ball color = green!10] (0,0) circle (\R); % 3D lighting effect           
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\coordinate[mark coordinate] (N) at (0,\H);
\coordinate[mark coordinate] (S) at (0,-\H);
\path[xzplane] (\R,0) coordinate (XE);
 %defining points outsided the area bounded by the sphere                       
\path[qzplane] (\angBeta:\R+3) coordinate (XEd);
\path[pzplane] (\angBeta:\R) coordinate (P);
\path[pzplane] (\angBeta:\R+3) coordinate (Pd);
\path[pzplane] (\angBeta:\R+5.2376) coordinate (Td);
\path[pzplane] (\R,0) coordinate (PE);
\path[pzplane] (\R+3,0) coordinate (PEd);
\path[qzplane] (\angBeta:\R) coordinate (Q);
\path[qzplane] (\angBeta:\R) coordinate (Qd);

\path[qzplane] (\R,0) coordinate (QE);
\path[qzplane] (\R+3,0) coordinate (QEd);


\DrawLongitudeCircle[\R]{\angPhiOne} % pzplane                                 
\DrawLongitudeCircle[\R]{\angPhiTwo} % qzplane                                 
\DrawLatitudeCircle[\R]{\angBeta}
\DrawLatitudeCircle[\R]{0} % equator                                           
% labelling north and south                                                    
\node[above = 8pt] at (N) {$\mathbf{N}$};
\node[below = 8pt] at (S) {$\mathbf{S}$};

\draw[-, dashed, thick] (N) -- (S);
%\draw[->] (O) -- (P);                                                         
%\draw[dashed] (XE) -- (O) -- (PE);                                            
\draw[dashed] (O) -- (QE);
% connecting Points outside the sphere                                         
\draw[-, dashed, black, very thick] (O) -- (Pd);
\draw[-, dashed, black, very thick] (O) -- (PEd);
\draw[-, dashed, black, very thick] (O) -- (QEd);
\draw[-, dashed, black, very thick] (O) -- (XEd);
\path[pzplane] (0.5*\angBeta:\R) node[right] {$$};
\path[qzplane] (0.5*\angBeta:\R) node[right] {$$};
\path[xzplane] (0:\R) node[below] {$$};
\path[xzplane] (\angBeta:\R) node[below left] {$$};
\foreach \t in {0,2,...,30} { \DrawLatitudeCirclered[\R]{\t} }
\foreach \t in {130,133,...,145} { \DrawLongitudeCirclered[\R]{\t} }

% drawing grids on the spere invoking DLongredd and DrawLongitudeCirclered     

\foreach \t in {130,145,...,145} { \DLongredd[\R+3]{\t} }
\foreach \t in {130,133,...,145} { \DrawLongitudeCirclered[\R+3]{\t} }

\foreach \t in {0,30,...,30} { \DLatred[\R+3]{\t} }
\foreach \t in {0,2,...,30} { \DrawLatitudeCirclered[\R+3]{\t} }
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{The normal pressure force of the surrounding water on $m$.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I just now attempted to compile you code, and I get the error `LaTeX Error: Command \DrawLongitudeCirclered already defined`. Also, I don't think @Jubobs was trying to be rude -- the "insist" was probably just intended to highlight the "M" and "W" in [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228).  There are numerous non-english speakers here so please try not to take offense.

Comment: @PeterGrill it compiles on my end see the attached picture that is the output.

Comment: @PeterGrill I copied and repasted the code to see that will help.

Comment: I get the same error as @PeterGrill when i compile your code. My guess is your code is built on a [texample.net example](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/spherical-and-cartesian-grids/). Kindly give credits or links to give a clear context in the question.

Comment: @texenthusiast link is above

Comment: Earlier MWE tested by @PeterGrill  was better compared to this as there is no \begin{document} and nothing after that.. Kindly _care_ to make sure the MWE is correct before posting.

Comment: @texenthusiast I already figured out after the first post I forgot the preamble so we can drop that issue because it was an accident and it is going to annoy me every other person needs to say hey don't forget that.

Comment: I was referring to [revision5](http://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/110991/5). Any i have to leave bye

Comment: Still does not compile for me with an updated TeXLive2012: `Runaway argument?
{>=latex, inner sep = 0pt,outer sep = 2pt,mark coordinate/.style = {i\ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \pgfkeys@@qset.`

Comment: I don't know why you provided a complete, long code while minimizing it is still possible to conforms to the MWE protocol. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created a solution using the primitives already defined in the not-so-minimal MWE. `:-)`

[image]

### Additions

Due to the length of the code, I'll explain my additions line-by-line; the complete code follows.

`\def\angPhiAvg{-42.5}`
defines angle phi for the vector to follow (in this case, the average of the grid extents).

`\LongitudePlane[myplane]{\angEl}{\angPhiAvg}`
defines an additional working plane in which the vector will lie.

`\path[myplane] (\angBeta/2:\R+3) coordinate (Ts);`
`\path[myplane] (\angBeta/2:\R+4) coordinate (Tf);`
define the start and finish of the vector; in this case, a unit length.

`\draw[->, green, very thick] (Ts) -- (Tf) node[right] {$\mathbf{\hat{n}}$};`
draws and labels the normal vector.

### Complete Code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,fadings,decorations.pathreplacing}

\newcommand\pgfmathsinandcos[3]{%                                                  
  \pgfmathsetmacro#1{sin(#3)}%                                                     
  \pgfmathsetmacro#2{cos(#3)}%                                                     
}
\newcommand\LongitudePlane[3][current plane]{%                                     
  \pgfmathsinandcos\sinEl\cosEl{#2} % elevation                                    
  \pgfmathsinandcos\sint\cost{#3} % azimuth                                        
  \tikzset{#1/.estyle = {cm = {\cost, \sint*\sinEl, 0, \cosEl, (0,0)}}}            
}
\newcommand\LatitudePlane[3][current plane]{%                                      
  \pgfmathsinandcos\sinEl\cosEl{#2} % elevation                                    
  \pgfmathsinandcos\sint\cost{#3} % latitude                                       
  \pgfmathsetmacro\yshift{\cosEl*\sint}                                            
  \tikzset{#1/.estyle = {cm = {\cost, 0, 0, \cost*\sinEl, (0,\yshift)}}} %         
}
\newcommand\DrawLongitudeCircle[2][1]{                                             
  \LongitudePlane{\angEl}{#2}                                                      
  \tikzset{current plane/.prefix style = {scale = #1}}                             
  % angle of "visibility"                                                          
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angVis{atan(sin(#2)*cos(\angEl)/sin(\angEl))} %                 
  \draw[current plane] (\angVis:1) arc (\angVis:\angVis + 180:1);                  
  \draw[current plane, dashed] (\angVis - 180:1) arc (\angVis - 180:\angVis:1);    
}
\newcommand\DrawLatitudeCircle[2][1]{                                              
  \LatitudePlane{\angEl}{#2}                                                       
  \tikzset{current plane/.prefix style = {scale = #1}}                             
  \pgfmathsetmacro\sinVis{sin(#2)/cos(#2)*sin(\angEl)/cos(\angEl)}                 
  % angle of "visibility"                                                          
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angVis{asin(min(1,max(\sinVis,-1)))}                            
  \draw[current plane] (\angVis:1) arc (\angVis:-\angVis - 180:1);                 
  \draw[current plane, dashed] (180 - \angVis:1) arc (180 - \angVis:\angVis:1);    
}
\newcommand\DrawLongitudeCirclered[2][1]{                                          
     \LongitudePlane{\angEl}{#2}                                                     
   \tikzset{current plane/.prefix style={scale=#1}}                                 
  % angle of "visibility"                                                          
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angVis{atan(sin(#2)*cos(\angEl)/sin(\angEl))} %                 
  \draw[current plane, blue, thick] (150:1) arc (150:180:1);                       
  % \draw[current plane,dashed] (-50:1) arc (-50:-35:1);                           
}%for drawing the grid                                                             
\newcommand\DLongredd[2][1]{                                                       
  \LongitudePlane{\angEl}{#2}                                                     
  \tikzset{current plane/.prefix style={scale=#1}}                                 
  % angle of "visibility"                                                          
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angVis{atan(sin(#2)*cos(\angEl)/sin(\angEl))} %                 
  \draw[current plane, black, dashed, ultra thick] (150:1) arc (150:180:1);        
}
\newcommand\DLatred[2][1]{                                                         
  \LatitudePlane{\angEl}{#2}                                                      
  \tikzset{current plane/.prefix style={scale=#1}}                                 
  \pgfmathsetmacro\sinVis{sin(#2)/cos(#2)*sin(\angEl)/cos(\angEl)}                 
  % angle of "visibility"                                                          
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angVis{asin(min(1,max(\sinVis,-1)))}                            
  \draw[current plane, dashed, black, ultra thick] (-50:1) arc (-50:-35:1);        
}
\newcommand  \fillred[2][1]{                                                         
  \LongitudePlane{\angEl}{#2}                                                     
  \tikzset{current plane/.prefix style={scale=#1}}                                 
  % angle of "visibility"                                                          
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angVis{atan(sin(#2)*cos(\angEl)/sin(\angEl))} %                 
  \draw[current plane, blue, thin] (\angVis:1) arc (\angVis:\angVis+180:1);        
}
\newcommand\DrawLatitudeCirclered[2][1]{                                           
  \LatitudePlane{\angEl}{#2}                                                      
  \tikzset{current plane/.prefix style={scale=#1}}                                 
  \pgfmathsetmacro\sinVis{sin(#2)/cos(#2)*sin(\angEl)/cos(\angEl)}                 
  % angle of "visibility"                                                          
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angVis{asin(min(1,max(\sinVis,-1)))}                            
% \draw[current plane,red,thick] (-\angVis-50:1) arc (-\angVis-50:-\angVis-20:1);  
  \draw[current plane, blue, thick] (-50:1) arc (-50:-35:1);                       
}


\tikzset{%                                                                        
  >=latex, % option for nice arrows                                               
  inner sep = 0pt,%                                                               
  outer sep = 2pt,%                                                               
  mark coordinate/.style = {inner sep = 0pt, outer sep = 0pt, minimum size = 3pt,
    fill = black, circle}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\R{2} % sphere radius                                                      

\def\angEl{25} % elevation angle                                               
\def\angAz{-100} % azimuth angle                                               
\def\angPhiOne{-50} % longitude of point P                                     
\def\angPhiTwo{-35} % longitude of point Q                       
\def\angPhiAvg{-42.5} % longitude of normal vector ******              
\def\angBeta{30} % latitude of point P and Q                                   

%% working planes                                                              

\pgfmathsetmacro\H{\R*cos(\angEl)} % distance to north pole                    
\LongitudePlane[xzplane]{\angEl}{\angAz}
\LongitudePlane[pzplane]{\angEl}{\angPhiOne}
\LongitudePlane[qzplane]{\angEl}{\angPhiTwo}
\LongitudePlane[myplane]{\angEl}{\angPhiAvg} % ******
\LatitudePlane[equator]{\angEl}{0}
\fill[ball color = green!10] (0,0) circle (\R); % 3D lighting effect           
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\coordinate[mark coordinate] (N) at (0,\H);
\coordinate[mark coordinate] (S) at (0,-\H);
\path[xzplane] (\R,0) coordinate (XE);
 %defining points outsided the area bounded by the sphere                       
\path[qzplane] (\angBeta:\R+3) coordinate (XEd);
\path[pzplane] (\angBeta:\R) coordinate (P);
\path[pzplane] (\angBeta:\R+3) coordinate (Pd);
\path[myplane] (\angBeta/2:\R+3) coordinate (Ts); % ******
\path[myplane] (\angBeta/2:\R+4) coordinate (Tf); % ******
\path[pzplane] (\R,0) coordinate (PE);
\path[pzplane] (\R+3,0) coordinate (PEd);
\path[qzplane] (\angBeta:\R) coordinate (Q);
\path[qzplane] (\angBeta:\R) coordinate (Qd);

\path[qzplane] (\R,0) coordinate (QE);
\path[qzplane] (\R+3,0) coordinate (QEd);


\DrawLongitudeCircle[\R]{\angPhiOne} % pzplane                                 
\DrawLongitudeCircle[\R]{\angPhiTwo} % qzplane                                 
\DrawLatitudeCircle[\R]{\angBeta}
\DrawLatitudeCircle[\R]{0} % equator                                           
% labelling north and south                                                    
\node[above = 8pt] at (N) {$\mathbf{N}$};
\node[below = 8pt] at (S) {$\mathbf{S}$};

\draw[-, dashed, thick] (N) -- (S);
%\draw[->] (O) -- (P);                                                         
%\draw[dashed] (XE) -- (O) -- (PE);                                            
\draw[dashed] (O) -- (QE);
% connecting Points outside the sphere                                         
\draw[-, dashed, black, very thick] (O) -- (Pd);
\draw[-, dashed, black, very thick] (O) -- (PEd);
\draw[-, dashed, black, very thick] (O) -- (QEd);
\draw[-, dashed, black, very thick] (O) -- (XEd);
\path[pzplane] (0.5*\angBeta:\R) node[right] {$$};
\path[qzplane] (0.5*\angBeta:\R) node[right] {$$};
\path[xzplane] (0:\R) node[below] {$$};
\path[xzplane] (\angBeta:\R) node[below left] {$$};
\foreach \t in {0,2,...,30} { \DrawLatitudeCirclered[\R]{\t} }
\foreach \t in {130,133,...,145} { \DrawLongitudeCirclered[\R]{\t} }
\draw[->, green, very thick] (Ts) -- (Tf) node[right] {$\mathbf{\hat{n}}$}; % ******

% drawing grids on the spere invoking DLongredd and DrawLongitudeCirclered     

\foreach \t in {130,145,...,145} { \DLongredd[\R+3]{\t} }
\foreach \t in {130,133,...,145} { \DrawLongitudeCirclered[\R+3]{\t} }

\foreach \t in {0,30,...,30} { \DLatred[\R+3]{\t} }
\foreach \t in {0,2,...,30} { \DrawLatitudeCirclered[\R+3]{\t} }
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{The normal pressure force of the surrounding water on $m$.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```